# Enter all list attribute values with one name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my list I have the attributes, "data-pic", "data-audio" and "data-word"...

```
<li data-audio="sounds/words/black.wav" data-pic="images/words/black.png" data-word="black"></li>
```

If I was going to change "black" to something else, is there a way I can change all attributes by inputting the new word once through HTML?

Comment: can you provide your probs in fiddle

Comment: If you have fixed set of attributed, you will have to run each of them through replace()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another, possibly shorter, method using jQuery:

```
$.each($("li").data(), function(key, value) {
    data[key] = value.replace("black", "white");
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hfK9n/)

You would probably want to use a placeholder value other than 'black' though.

Comment: By place holder value do you mean ""? @Rory McCrossan

Comment: I mean something like `{{value}}`. It's just a formatted value to replace, which is unlikely to occur normally within the string.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a javascript function..

```
function writeLi(color){
    return '<li data-audio="sounds/words/'+color+'.wav" data-pic="images/words/'+color+'.png" data-word="'+color+'"></li>'
}
```

How about that?

Comment: Ye that seems to be what I am looking for. Is there a way of putting it in through HTML though? @Wozzner

Comment: what if he once has an "mp3" audio file? once an jpg, gif or svg image to display? :)

Comment: Where do you want to place it?

Answer (score 1):

You could take advantage of the attributes array, this is just a simple example, depending on your situation you may need a more advanced way to replace "black" other than a straight replacement like this.

```
var el = document.getElementById("yourList");
for( var i = 0, max = el.attributes.length; i < max; i++ ){
 if( el.attributes[i].nodeName.indexOf("data") > -1 ){
  el.attributes[i].nodeValue.replace("black","newValue");
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works too:

```
var elem = $("li")[0];
var attrs = elem.attributes;
for(var i=0;i<attrs.length;i++) {
   $(elem).attr(attrs[i].nodeName,attrs[i].nodeValue.replace(/black/gi,'white'));                                               
}
​
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
var myWord = $('li').data('word');
var newWord = 'blue';

$('li').data('word', newWord);

$('li').data('audio', $('li').data('audio').replace(myWord, newWord));
$('li').data('pic', $('li').data('pic').replace(myWord, newWord));
```

But this would be a bad approach. Best would be:

```
$('li').data('word', 'yellow');
$('li').data('audio', 'sounds/words/yellow.wav');
$('li').data('pic', 'images/words/yellow.png');
```

Answer (score -1):

jQuery:

```
$('div.#ContainerName li').each(function(a,li) {
  if(this.attr('data-word') == 'black') {
    li.attr('data-word', yourNewValueHere)
    li.attr('data-audio', yourNewValueHere1)
    li.attr('data-pic', yourNewValueHere2)
  }
});
```

Use containername to limit scope if needed (otherwise it will check all LIs and that may be too many/too slow/undesirable)

Comment: use "$.data" to read "data-*" attributes. also your example only changes the "data-word" attribute, not values of the "data-audio", "data-pic"

Comment: You downvoted it because there's *another* way of doing it? Or it conflicts with your answer? This is programming, there are numerous ways of everything. Unless my way doesn't work then you're being disingenuous.

Comment: Feedback is fine, like edit my post. But downvoting it is saying "this answer is incorrect" when actually you're saying "there is a better way".

Comment: well the important thing is that you're correct now about this: "this answer is incorrect" when actually you're saying "there is a better way".